# What were the Jurchen tribes/confederations in the 11th-12th centuries?

Tags: middle-ages, 12th-century, 11th-century, medieval-china

I couldn't find anything about them other than vague geographical localization.
Basically, I'm looking for the highest tribal organizations (no need to cite every single clan), akin to the five Mongol Khanligs to the west.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there was any tribal organisation as such. Starting with [Wanyan Wugunai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wanyan_Wugunai) circa mid-11th century, the [**Wanyan Tribe**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wanyan) became dominant among the Jurchens. Successive Wanyan chieftains gradually unified the Jurchen tribes as [**hereditary `jiédùshǐ`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiedushi) of the [Liao Empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liao_dynasty), and also took the Jurchen title of **`begile`**.

By 1115, the new *begile* [Wanyen Akuta (Wanyan Aguda)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_Taizu_of_Jin) revolted against the [Khitan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khitan_people) Liao Empire, founding the Jurchen [**Great Jin Empire**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_dynasty_(1115%E2%80%931234)) in the process. So You might justifiably call the Great Jin the "highest tribal organisation" of 12th century Jurchens.

---

This is an incomplete list of Jurchen clans around the rise of the Wanyan:

- `Wanyan`: from the [Ashi/Anchuhu River](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acheng_District)
- `Wulinda`: from the Hailang River
- `Wendu`: from the Lalin River
- `Jiagu`: from around [Wuchang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wuchang,_Heilongjiang).
- `Wole`: from north of the [Ashi/Anchuhu River](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acheng_District)
- `Tangguo`: from the [Paektu Mountain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paektu_Mountain)
- `Adian`: from one of the tributaries of the [Liao River](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liao_River)
- Various `Helandian` clans: from around modern [Hamhung City](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamhung)
- Various `Wugulun` clans: possibly from the Wugulun river basin
- Eight `Boli` clans: where the [Amur River](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amur_River) meets the [Ussuri River](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ussuri_River)
- The `Five Country Clans`

Comment: That may be the reason why I couldn't find anything: probably there wasn't anything to be found. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Just one last quick question: the Wanyan clan seems to be really dominant in the Jin politics, but what about the others? Was there a second clan?

Comment: @BrunoHeblingVieira They really weren't that dominant, rather they rose very quickly after the 11th century. Around the time, I get the impression that the Wulinda clan was quite influential; they joined the Wanyan during Aguda's father's chiefdom, and was evidently important enough that Aguda married a Wulinda princess. A couple of generations earlier, the Wulinda even seized the then-Wanyan chieftain's coffin in a show of force.

Comment: I've found some information about the first Jurchen confederation: the Wuguobu was a confederation uniting the Punuli, Tieli, Yuelidu, Aolimi, and Puali tribes. It was founded by Wanyan Wugunai, a military commisioner for the Da Liao. Around the end of the 11th century, the Tudan, Wugulun and Pucha challenged the dominance of the Wanyan but were subjugated. The souce is my favourite guide on Chinese history: chinaknowledge.de